# How to transfer internet audio streams to ipad?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization

I opened all my internet audio streams in iTunes and copied all of them into an iTunes playlist.

I would like to sync this playlist with the one on my iPad iTunes but I can't. When I select my iPad from iTunes this playlist is missing from the playlists.

[image: /Users/boti/Desktop/Screen Shot 2014-09-23 at 3.55.19 PM.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Music app on iOS doesn't support Audio streams. If you want to listen to audio streams on iPhone/iPad you can use one of the various streaming apps available in the App Store (e.g. WunderRadio, TUneIn Radio or Radium).

Comment: are those Siri compatible?

Comment: Honestly I don't know, but I doubt it. AFAIK 3rd party apps aren't Siri compatible at all

Comment: My original intention was to use Siri to play audio streams, because there are 4000 channels in macbook iTunes internet tab. I wanted to do the same with my iPad... Can I do that somehow?

Comment: It might be worth to ask a *new* question for this (including a link to the one here might provide some reference).